# docker hub repo

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have created a repo on my docker hub account. While trying to download it it shows errors. I have tried the following commands:

- `docker id saurabhgore65`
- `docker pull <saurabhgore65>/subash`
- `docker pull <saurabhgore65>/subash:latest`
- `docker pull <saurabhgore65>/subash:sagoreimage`

As you told there is nothing in the docker hub repository. What are subash and sagore a

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Please add the error logging. Without it, it will be hard to help. Please let me know when you have added the log.

Answer (score 0):

Try below cmd to pull the images from dockerhub:

`sudo docker pull username/reponame:latest[tag]`

*ie.*

`sudo docker pull iakshaykr/dochub:tom`

above:
- iakshaykr (username for docker hub account) 
- dochub (repo created on my dochub)
- tom is image which i have pushed ,in your case it is tag which you wants to pull

I looked into your repo and found that you haven't pushed any image till now into your repo ,so you can't pull. First push an image from your local repo then you can able to pull.

`docker pull saurabhgore65/subash:[tag]`

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have entered `docker login` in the cli.  After that it really depends on the error you are getting.  You may need to use an elevate permissions (i.e., Admin powershell console or `sudo` prefixed to the pull commands).

As stated in another answer there is currently nothing in [your docker hub repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/saurabhgore65/subash).  To fix this you should first build an image `docker build . -t myimagename` from your dockerfile.  Next you will need to push the image: `docker push saurabhgore65/subash`.  If you do not specify a tag then it will default tag as "latest".  Once something is in your repository you should be able to pull it.